# jQuery bind or live not working as expected in my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm writing a plugin for jQuery that wraps a span element around an input (text) element. When I bind() or live() the form element input to add/remove classes to its parent  element, the binding does not work. Consider the following;

```
(function($){
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function() {

    var $this, $tag;

    return this.each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $tag = $(document.createElement('span'));
        $this.wrap($tag).bind('mouseover',function(){
            $tag.addClass('hover');
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Using Google Chrome and viewing the elements and console output, I expect to see the 'hover' class added to the span element when I move my simulate a mouseover event. However nothing happens. If I print the $tag variable to the console after I add the hover class, it does appear correct in the console output.

I'm guessing this has something to do with variable scope but I'm lost trying to work out a solution.

Comment: as an aside, you don't need `document.createElement`; `$this.wrap("<span></span>")`...

Comment: I read somewhere that $(document.createElement()) is faster than ('<span>'). I can't find the link right now though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).wrap('<span>').bind('mouseover',function(){
                $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), when used with a jQuery object or a DOM element, clones that element and uses the copy to wrap the selection.  From the API:

> [wrap] doesn't move the object but just clones it to wrap around its target

Your code is adding a class to an element that has never been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Works perfect! And your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you very much (and to all others below who have also provided responses)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return this.each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $tag = $(document.createElement('span'));
    $this.wrap($tag);
    $tag.bind('mouseover',function(){
        $tag.addClass('hover');
    });
}
```

If I'm not mistaken does wrap return `$this` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function() {

        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).wrap("<span></span>")
            $(this).parent('span').live('mouseover',function(){
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```